# Closing JAX-RS StreamingOutput's OutputStream

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, cxf

**Should the `StreamingOutput`'s `OutputStream` be closed by the implementing class?**

The java-doc does not give any recommendations. I guess it just delegates to the underlying `ServletOutputStream` which means it should not be closed, but my guess might be wrong :) Also the javadoc makes a reference to the `MessageBodyWriter` interface where it's explicitly said that the output stream must not be closed.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html

Comment: I don't think you should close it. There might be filters or interceptors downstream which might break if you close the output stream.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Being unable to find a definitive answer I took a look at jersey's source being the reference implementation. In Jersey the `StreamingOutput` is processed by a `MessageBodyWriter` by simply calling `streamingOutput.write(os)` [1] where `os` is the `OutputStream` passed to the `MessageBodyWriter`. That's good because its javadoc is quite clear that this `OutputStream` **must not** be closed.

**To summarize: The `OutputStream` passed to the `StreamingOutput` must not be closed.**

[1] https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/StreamingOutputProvider.java

Comment: Excellent and very helpful Q&A.  It is a shame this documentation is missing from the Javadocs for `interface StreamingOutput`!